# Application disapproved, want to change site, cannot do anything?

Tags: adsense

1. I have a Google Account for a long time.
2. I have created a blog using Blogspot (let's call it SITE A).
3. I have registered my blog to AdSense using my name, street address and phone number and waited for approval.
4. I have received an email saying that my application was disapproved

At this point I have the following "possibilities":

a) cancel my AdSense account and start again 
b) change my site (to a new SITE B) in my AdSense application 
c) create a new Google Account and apply for adsense with the new site (SITE B) 
d) delete my google account

However, I discovered that NONE of these really work as:

a) I cannot cancel an account that doesn't exist. Unless an AdSense application is approved, my account doesn't exist and cannot therefore be "canceled".
b) I cannot change my site to SITE B, as the web interface won't let me.

[http://i.imgur.com/nUTw6.png](https://i.imgur.com/nUTw6.png)

c) should work just fine, except for the fact i cannot use my name, my address or my phone number as google disapproves these requests if another application request has been already made with that information.

d) My application is still going to be there if I delete my account and create it later. Moreover, it's stupid to delete my account which I used for the past 6 years for a thing like this.

So..

1. My only hope is that someday, somehow, SITE A will be approved, althogh I know it won't since it's just an empty test blog.. ?
2. I feel that Google Adsense is more like Google Nonsense after this experience.
3. They should warn you that once you make an application, it's FOREVER.

I cannot email for support either because they don't have any support email displayed anywhere. They have a support form that is only available in the Google AdSense Account panel which I cannot access since I don't have one.

Comment: have you get your answer or not?

Comment: Yes, Google said it was disapproved, without giving any reason.

Comment: if it is disapprove then you are eligible to replay after some times.For some country google gives adsense only after 6 month of creating the blog...check for that also...

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced the same problem. I have 2 blog one of sports and another is about my personal ideas with single gmail account. First I applied adsense to sport blog but it was disapproved(due to which I couldn't apply it for my another personal blog with that gmail account). So later I made admin to another gmail account on my personal blog that I had created and filled the information that I had before on applying on adsense with first gmail account. After that My adsense was approved. Adsense being disapproved doesn't meant you aren't able to re-apply but if once you create an adsense account and it is disabled means you aren't able to re-apply later with same name and phone number.

So, if your blog content are original and don't contain large number of external link then you can apply by creating another account. Another funny case also happened with my friend. i.e one of my friend had created blog and applied for adsense but that was disapproved, When he made another friend(eg B) admin and apply on adsense through B's account for same blog and get approved.I don't know why this was happening (note: Here I added my experience because It may help you on figuring the possible solution.)

Answer (score -2):

You can re-apply for AdSense for the same site if your site meets the policies and criteria for the site.

Comment: I don't want to apply wtih the same site, as it's just an empty site. I have another personal blog 2 years old, 300+ posts that i want to use but I didn't own a domain for it when I applied for adsense. Now I have.. but I cannot apply anymore.